# How to set the proper connection parameters to connect a SQL Server database in Atom Editor using Data-Atom package?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, atom-editor

I'm trying to use [Data-Atom](https://atom.io/packages/data-atom) package in the *Atom Editor* to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database. I can connect to the database with *SQL Server Managment* Studio using **Windows Authentication** or **SQL Server Authentication**. How the `data-atom-connections.cson` file should be using these two authentication methods?

My `data-atom-connections.cson` file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "WindowsAuthentication"
    protocol: "sqlserver"
    user: "username"
    password: "password"
    server: "apphost/Username"
    database: "master"
    options: ""
  }
{
    name: "SQLServerAuthentication"
    protocol: "sqlserver"
    user: "userlogin"
    password: "password"
    server: "apphost/sqlexpress"
    database: "master"
    options: ""
  }
]
```

But I get this error:

```
Error(ESOCKET) - Failed to connect to apphost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.56.1:1433
```

**Note**: for specifying the server name I saw this post [Logging In to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188642.aspx)

Comment: When you connect with Management Studio, do you do it from the same machine?  Or do you remote desktop onto the server and run it there?

Comment: @DzamoNorton, I did it using the same machine!

Comment: Ah I see you're trying to connect to _named_ instances though.  I've just got Windows authn to SQL Server working for data-atom and I'll add support for named instances too.  I'll post back here when it's ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [this pull request](https://github.com/lukemurray/data-atom/pull/113) is merged into data-atom you should have more luck.

- Enter `SERVER\INSTANCE` in the server field, or `SERVER\\INSTANCE` if you're editing `data-atom-connections.cson` directly, to connect to a named instance.
- Add the option `domain=YOUR_DOMAIN` to the options string to use Windows authentication (see [more options for SQL Server here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql))
- If you don't want to wait for the code to be merged into upstream and a new release, take it [straight from my repo](https://github.com/DzamoNorton/data-atom/tree/urlrefactor) and place/link under `~/.atom/packages`.
- The protocol part of the URL has changed to `mssql` for SQL Server to align with `node-mssql`.