# How to connect a database in Atom Editor?

Tags: sql, database, atom-editor

I want to connect my database in atom and execute directly from the editor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Install a package "data-atom" [Reference](https://atom.io/packages/data-atom). You can do it in two ways :

1.Through command line (windows) :

```
 apm install data-atom
```

make sure you have ssl false, if not then type

```
apm config set strict-ssl false
```

before "apm install"

2.Open atom and go to settings and click on "+Install" and look for "data-atom" package.

Once you downloaded, restart atom and do "alt+shift+r" to open database window. Fill in the configuration and you are good to go.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Install data-atom as recommended already by Sdembla. But beware, the recommended commands in the documentation for these packages do **not** work, until you **first use "Edit connections", to create a connections file** for it to work with.

Interestingly this also applied to the "data-ace" Atom package.

The exact steps (assuming you've installed the data-atom package, and restarted Atom) are...

- click Packages > Data Atom > Edit connections
- replace the generic file contents ("[ ]") with a connection config, like that shown in guzman's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197644/how-to-set-the-proper-connection-parameters-to-connect-a-sql-server-database-in):

`[
  {
    name: "WindowsAuthentication"
    protocol: "sqlserver"
    user: "username"
    password: "password"
    server: "apphost/Username"
    database: "master"
    options: ""
  }
{
    name: "SQLServerAuthentication"
    protocol: "sqlserver"
    user: "userlogin"
    password: "password"
    server: "apphost/sqlexpress"
    database: "master"
    options: ""
  }
]`

- the other commands (eg ctrl-shift-R) should now work
- it's important you Save this connections file, otherwise the commands will stop working again.